# Multi-character character sequence in 3rd party library

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using a 3rd party library for an iOS project I work on, and I'm down to one warning left in the project, namely on this line of code

```
[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:'oaut']
```

And the warning is

```
Multi-character character constant
```

I suck at C, so I don't know how to fix this, but I'm sure the fix is relatively easy. Help?

EDIT: More context.

```
@implementation MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore (KeychainAdditions)

- (void)addToKeychainUsingName:(NSString *)inName andValue:(NSString *)inValue {
    NSString *serverName = [self.baseURL host];
    NSString *securityDomain = [self.authenticationURL host];
//  NSString *itemID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.oauth.%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier], inName];
    NSDictionary *searchDictionary = nil;
    NSDictionary *keychainItemAttributeDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: (id)kSecClassInternetPassword, kSecClass,
                                                                                                securityDomain, kSecAttrSecurityDomain,
                                                                                                serverName, kSecAttrServer,
                                                                                                inName, kSecAttrAccount,
                                                                                                kSecAttrAuthenticationTypeDefault, kSecAttrAuthenticationType,
                                                                                                [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:"oaut"], kSecAttrType,
                                                                                                [inValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], kSecValueData,
                                                     nil];


    if ([self findValueFromKeychainUsingName:inName returningItem:&searchDictionary]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *updateDictionary = [keychainItemAttributeDictionary mutableCopy];
        [updateDictionary removeObjectForKey:(id)kSecClass];

        SecItemUpdate((CFDictionaryRef)keychainItemAttributeDictionary, (CFDictionaryRef)updateDictionary);
        [updateDictionary release];
    } else {
        OSStatus success = SecItemAdd( (CFDictionaryRef)keychainItemAttributeDictionary, NULL);

        if (success == errSecNotAvailable) {
            [NSException raise:@"Keychain Not Available" format:@"Keychain Access Not Currently Available"];
        } else if (success == errSecDuplicateItem) {
            [NSException raise:@"Keychain duplicate item exception" format:@"Item already exists for %@", keychainItemAttributeDictionary];
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: They were attempting to meet the requirements of this by creating that NSNumber:

```
@constant kSecAttrType Specifies a dictionary key whose value is the item's
        type attribute. You use this key to set or get a value of type
        CFNumberRef that represents the item's type. This number is the
        unsigned integer representation of a four-character code (e.g.,
        'aTyp').
```

Comment: Looks like a typo as 'oaut' is definitely not an unsigned long long.  What number is it supposed to have in there?

Comment: yAak: I think it supposed to have it, that's the crazy part. Updated post with more context.

Comment: Thinking about this, I remembered that multi-character character constants are/were possible in C (up to four characters, IIRC). Perhaps 'oaut' was really meant to be such a character, used as int and promoted to unsigned long long. 'oaut' are the first characters of "oauth", which is used in the code. Apparently CodeWarrior accepted such code.

Comment: @refulgentis: posted my reply as an answer

Comment: Your Edit 2 seems spot on. That must be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C and Obj-C the single-quote `'` is used only for single-character constants. You need to use the double-quote: `"`

Like so:

```
[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:"oaut"]
```

That covers the warning, but there's also a semantic issue here. Although a single character constant, such as `'o'`, can be treated as an integer (and can be promoted to an `unsigned long long`), a "string" (`char *` or `char []`) cannot, which means you can't use `"oaut"` as an argument to `numberWithUnsignedLongLong:`

Update:

I guess the four-character code is supposed to be treated as an integer, i.e., the 8 bits of each `char` put in place as if they together were a 32-bit `int`:

```
char code[] = "oaut";
uint32_t code_as_int = code[0] | (code[1] << 8) | (code[2] << 16) | (code[3] << 24);

[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:code_as_int]
```

although I'm not sure which endianness would be expected here, nor why this is calling for an `unsigned long long`, unless just to be certain there are enough bits.

Rudy's comment, now that I think of it, is correct -- multi-character constants are allowed by some compilers for exactly this purpose (it is "implementation-defined" behavior).

Comment: Hrm, should have tried that first, obvious answer. But now I have sending 'char[5]' to parameter of type long long, which is true. What an odd piece of code.

Comment: Saw your edit. Have to wonder what the heck they were trying to do here.

Comment: Maybe `oaut` is a symbol from an `enum` somewhere, and the quotes aren't supposed to be there at all? Or it's a poorly-styled `#define`d constant?

Comment: No, they're attempting to pass an object reference to an unsigned integer representation of a four-character code. Which is a bit insane itself, but Keychain on OS X/iOS has a reputation for that, IIRC.

Comment: Oh, I get it. You have to stuff those four characters into a 32-bit `int`.

Comment: Thanks! One last question: I already used atoi('oaut') instead, is that equivalent to your solution or is there a line mine there?

Comment: The man page for `atoi` says to use `strtol`, but I don't think that's what you want anyways -- those functions treat the string as a written representation of a number, i.e., `atoi("1234")` will give you an `int` whose value is one thousand, two hundred, and thirty-four. `'oaut'` isn't a valid number representation in any base lower than 20-something, so I think you'll just get `0` back from those functions.

Answer (score 1):

`'oaut'` (single quotes) is a character, so the compiler tries to interpret it as a multi-byte character but can't make any sense of it. That explains the error message.

I guess that if you gave a proper string, like @"oaut", you'd get another error message, since `numberWithUnsignedLongLong:` expects an `unsigned long long`, not a string or a character. Are you trying to pass a variable with the name "oaut"? If so, use

```
[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong: oaut];
```

If not, then please explain what "oaut" is.

**Edit**

`'oaut'` may actually be the original value. There are/were multi-character character constants in C. Using a (4 byte) `char`, used as `int` and promoted to `unsigned long long` would then be possible. This must be old code. It seems such code was accepted by CodeWarrior.

Assuming that really a multi-char char const was meant, `'oaut'` looks like a "magic number" and this value was chosen because it is the beginning of `"oauth"`. I guess it should either be value 0x6F617574 or 0x7475616F.

Answer (score 0):

@Josh Caswell 's answer is partially right, the simplest and "official" solution is:

```
[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:'oaut']
```

`unsigned int`'s length is 32-bit in both 32-bit and 64-bit cpu, there's a practical example from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Listings/Classes_SecKeyWrapper_m.html